# Send mail from Contact form

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

I have issues with getting mail after a user has sendt the contact form.

I have used this one before and it worked at first, but then it stopped working and now i cant get it to work again.

I use the one from freecontactform.com

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "you@yourdomain.com";

    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>
```

I just change the

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$email_to = "you@yourdomain.com";

$email_subject = "Your email subject line";

To my mail and subject. And i change everything that is entered into the contact form, but i dont alter the function of the script.

Why aint this one working? I have seen people write that it works, but for me it aint working. I have also tried several other scripts for sending mail but they aint sending any mail at all.

Anyone that can explain how this works and if they know about a script that works?

Thanks.

Comment: (important) side-note:dont validate email addresses like that, dont validate names(at all)

Comment: Are you testing this locally or on a server? If a server, which company are you using?

Comment: I have been testing locally and on servetheworld.net